# Can't understand a point using insertion sort in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, insertion-sort

> *it's a insertion sort algorithm*

I understand forwarding the greatest no to next index but cant understand when it moves forward how its previous position (index) is being taken by the smaller number that was just compare e.g  in list [2,1]  2 moves to next index by list[j+1]=list[j]; but how 1 moves backward or to previous index

```
 //unsorted array   
int[] list = new int[] { 5, 2, 4, 6, 1 };   

// the key element being sorted   
int key;   
// 
//start looping starting from the second element  
for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; i++)   
{  
    key = list[i];//store the key 
    int j = i - 1;//get the previous index  
    //
    //loop until you meet a smaller number or 0 
    while (j >= 0 && list[j] > key)  
    { 
        //move the greater number forward  
        list[j + 1] = list[j];  
        // Decrementing  
        j--;   
    }  
    //set the key in the proper index  
    list[j + 1] = key; 
}
```

Comment: Some formatting of your question would be nice.

Comment: I fixed your editing.  You need to get rid of the line numbers and realize that anything in SO with 4 spaces becomes code.  Also, the text at the fron doesn't need to be a quote - just text.

Comment: The answer is in the last line: `list[j + 1] = key;`. The number being tested is placed at the right spot after all higher numbers are moved up. If it was at correct place initially j will be `i - 1` and thus `j + 1` will be `i`.

Comment: Am I the only person who can't understand any phrase here consisting of > 4 words?

Comment: Plz check all the tags i choose if you have a good knowledge about c# insertion sort it wont b hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done in the last line inside the loop. After moving one or more (or even zero) items forward, the current value is put in the correct position.

For example, if you have sorted the array up to the last item, and it looks like this:

```
2, 4, 5, 6, 1
```

The value 1 is copied into the `key` variable, then items are copied forward one by one:

```
2, 4, 5, 6, -   <-  the empty slot here still contains 1, but it's unused
2, 4, 5, -, 6   <-  the empty slot here still contains 6, but it's unused
2, 4, -, 5, 6
2, -, 4, 5, 6
-, 2, 4, 5, 6
```

Now the value from the `key` variable is placed where the last item was copied from:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 6
```

---

The theory behind the insert sort is to take items from one array and insert into a new array. The implementation that you are using is only using a single array, and you can think of it as divided into a sorted part and an unsorted part. The sorted part starts out with the size zero:

```
[][ 5, 2, 4, 6, 1 ]
```

when the array is sorted, items are picked from the unsorted part and are inserted at the right place in the sorted part. The sorted part grows and the unsorted part shrinks, until the unsorted part is empty:

```
[ 5 ][ 2, 4, 6, 1 ]
[ 2, 5 ][ 4, 6, 1 ]
[ 2, 4, 5 ][ 6, 1 ]
[ 2, 4, 5, 6 ][ 1 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ][]
```

Comment: Your answer make sense but i m still confuse becoz wn 6 moves to last index the key value is 4 and it is pointing on 6 and i dont know what is happening next could you plz give an example about your last sentence

Comment: @Ted: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but I tried to make it clearer, and added something about the theory behind the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the right track and it contains a single array and it look like divided in two parts and the key holds one value at each iteration for the while loop and that's where i was confuse and for the case  2 3 4 1 it iterates like this                     2 3 4 4 , 2 3 3 4 , 2 2 3 4 as the j value becomes less then 0 j becomes -1 then the last instruction       list[ j+1] = key which was 1 for the last index placed at j[0] as -1+1 = 0;

Comment: And please vote up for my question so i may get 15 reputation and vote up your answer. again thanks again as i m preparing for my exams.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are TWO lists/arrays
The declaration at the top...

int[] list = new int[] { 5, 2, 4, 6, 1 };

Says to make a list/array of integer format called X 
X being whatever name you give it...

In this case the lists/arrays are list/array I[] and list/array J[]

So it (most likely) could be READING from one list/array maybe the I[] list/array
and assigning the SORTED values into the other list/array maybe the J[] list/array
```

Comment: Its not a build in list array its just the name of my array and i cant understand what you have said

Comment: There are TWO lists LIST i() and List j() and its done in the LAST line as the Nikola said

Comment: Bahi its a insertion sort i have just used int array name list and there is only one array becoz j is just pointing to some index in the list array